# Get image as an object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

> Uploading image from single upload form works fine. Code that i use:

### View:

```
<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
```

### Controller

```
$input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);
Gallery::create($input);


return back()->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.');
```

> But i need to change previous view so images will belong to array with specific key:

### View:

```
<input type="file" name="quiz[777][image]" class="form-control">
```

### Controller [ problem ]

```
$input['image'] = time().'.'.Input::get('quiz')[777]['image'])->getClientOriginalExtension();
Input::get('quiz')[777]['image'])->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);
Gallery::create($input);


return back()->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.');
```

In controller now i am getting errors, that image is not an object and so i cant use **getClientOriginalExtension()** and **move** methods.

I also tried `$request->Input::get('quiz')[777]['image'])` but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Input::file()` to get uploaded file

```
$input['image'] = time().'.'.Input::file('quiz')[777]['image'])->getClientOriginalExtension();
Input::file('quiz')[777]['image'])->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);
```

Comment: i do not have file method in Input class, why ?

This works : echo Input::get('quiz')[777]['image'];

This does not :  echo Input::file('quiz')[777]['image'];

Comment: please show what `dd(Input::all())` gives, its not about file method and `Input` class do have file method

Comment: this works : print_r( $request->get('quiz')[0]['image']); this does not: print_r( $request->file('quiz')[0]['image']); So i am getting error Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Comment: did you add multipart header on your form?? add your full view form

Comment: glad its working now, sometimes we forgot tiny little things which cause our head burst out :D

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `Input::get()` `use Input::file();`

So change this

```
Input::get('quiz')[777]['image'])->getClientOriginalExtension();
Input::get('quiz')[777]['image'])->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);
```

to this

```
request()->file('quiz')[777]['image'])->getClientOriginalExtension();
request()->file('quiz')[777]['image'])->move(public_path('images'), $input['image']);
```

Comment: i do not have file method in Input class, why ?

This works : echo Input::get('quiz')[777]['image'];

This does not :  echo Input::file('quiz')[777]['image'];

Comment: @uppermost Input::file('quiz')[777]['image'] you shoud try `request()`

Comment: this works :         print_r( $request->get('quiz')[0]['image']);

this does not:  print_r( $request->file('quiz')[0]['image']);

So i am getting error  Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null